# iOS Appium 1.9 - Clicking on parent of element using iOS Class Chain

Tags: appium, appium-ios, python-appium

I have an image within a collection view that I am unable to click on. Appium can find the element fine but using the `is_displayed()` function always returns false. I read up on the iOS Class chain function so attempted to use that to click on the images parent `XCUIElementTypeCell` (Which can be clicked on, but has no label, or name value annoyingly)

My attempt:

```
self._driver.find_element(By.IOS_CLASS_CHAIN, "**/XCUIElementTypeImage[`name BEGINSWITH \"Click Me\"`]/**/XCUIElementTypeOther/**/XCUIElementTypeCell")
```

This gives a `NoSuchElementException`

The app structure looks like this:
[image: Screenshot of a sample of the app structure]

So that `XCUIElementTypeImage` in the centre is what I am trying to target using name which equals "click me" in this example. The parent `XCUIElementTypeOther` also can be found but is not clickable so the only solution for me is jump up two levels to the `XCUIElementTypeCell`

P.S Please no Xpath suggestions

P.S2 Thanks for the help

Comment: So, you want to go to the first XCUIElementTypeCell? Why don't you try this:
**/XCUIElementTypeCollectionView/XCUIElementTypeCell[1].
AFAIK, we can't go to parent elements in ios Class Chain.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
"**/XCUIElementTypeCell[$type=XCUIElementTypeImage AND name BEGINSWITH 'Click Me'$]"
```

OR

```
"**/XCUIElementTypeCell[$type='XCUIElementTypeImage' AND name BEGINSWITH 'Click Me'$]"
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go, what does the '$' sign refer to exactly?

Comment: Doesn't work, seems that it's picking up the internal element. I've managed to get it working by using an xpath command and adding "parent::XCUIElementTypeOther" on the end, so it's not too long

Comment: @Alesia D, I think you have to put  type == 'XCUIElementTypeImage', instead of single equal symbol.

Comment: please help i am facing the same issue - in app structure it showing <XCUIElementTypeWindow>
<XCUIElementTypeOther>
<XCUIElementTypeOther>
<XCUIElementTypeOther>
<XCUIElementTypeOther>
<XCUIElementTypeOther>
<XCUIElementTypeOther>
<XCUIElementTypeNavigationBar name="">
<XCUIElementTypeCell>   I have to click on XCUIElementType cell - the last element i copied